# Random graphs as random variable

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-graphs

> The $G (n, p)$ model, due to Erdös and Rényi, has two parameters, $n$
> and $p$. Here $n$ is the number of vertices of the graph and $p$ is
> the edge probability. For each pair of distinct vertices, $v$ and $w,
> > p$ is the probability that the edge $(v,w)$ is present. The presence
> of each edge is statistically independent of all other edges. The
> graph-valued random variable with these parameters is denoted by $G(n,p)$. When we refer to “the graph $G(n,p)$”, we mean one realization
> of the random variable

Random graphs are random variables?

I thought that $G(n,p)$ is a random variable with $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is $\mathcal{P}\{1,...,n\}^2,\mathcal{P}\{\mathcal{P}\{1,...,n\}^2\},1/|\mathcal{P}\{1,...,n\}^2|$ and $G(n,p)(\omega)= |\omega|^p|\{1,...,n\}^2|-|\omega|^{1-p}$. But if that would be the case I don t know how I can formally verify that the event that an edge is present is stochastically independed that an oher edge is present. I have chosen the model to look at all possible sets of edges ie all graphs possible, the author of this paper (J.Spencer) mentioned a graph-valued random variable hence I thought I have to find a probabiliypace where an elemen represents a graph.

**If someone could tell me how I can verify the stochastic independence of the existence of two edges and how the random graphs are modeled as random variables I would really appreciate it**

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: if I should not use pictures why there is an option to add pictures? Also it is a screensho of a paper and not something handwriten

Comment: The point is that your picture is not visible to the visually impaired.  Pictures on the SE network are for illustration purposes.  They aren't a substitute to typing the text.

Comment: I have now edited the text of the piture, why do you want to close immediatley?

Comment: To stop users from getting rewards by answering pic questions.  Please use MathJax to typeset math.

Comment: I have edited it so it is not a pic question anymore.

Comment: Please also edit your quoted text so that the variables inside would be typeset in MathJax

Comment: I have edited again now please remove the dislike so people will look at my question

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 "Stopping users from getting rewards by answering pic questions" seems like a ridiculous goal. If you feel that strongly, why not edit these questions to fix them?

Comment: @MishaLavrov We shouldn't encourage questions which are not user-friendly.  Pic questions are unfriendly to visually impaired users.  Getting points from answering a question is a rewarding process.  So I won't hesitate to cast a close vote to stop users from answering questions which aren't user-friendly.

Comment: @MishaLavrov It's OP's responsibility to make his/her own question clear for others, especially visually impaired users, who can't view the images through a screen reader.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 And I'm not sure what this has to do with other people answering the question.

Comment: when one answers a pic question, its question asker is offered freely an answer for a question that lacks clarity, especially for the visually impaired. that would encourage him/her to post another pic question.  Here's an example of pic questions posted by the same user again and again: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3926583, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3956979/290189, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3978064/290189.  We do have

Comment: @MishaLavrov some [high-rep user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595342/numerical-evaluation-of-an-integral-similar-to-an-exponential-integral/595359#comment1257012_595359) who has to view posts using assistive technologies.  Under the current "be-kind" policy, they shouldn't be hindered from viewing the contents of this question.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 It seems like they'll also be hindered from viewing the contents of the question if the question is downvoted, closed and deleted before they get a chance to answer it. Anyway, this doesn't seem like the best place to continue this discussion, but I remain skeptical. I do, however, agree with the broader idea that questions with large blocks of text in image form are bad!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Random graphs are a random variable, but not a *real-valued* random variable: a graph-valued one. $G(n,p)$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the set of all $2^{\binom n2}$ graphs on a fixed vertex set $\{v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n\}$.

So what's the sample space, then? We could be lazy and just take $\Omega$ to be the same set of graphs, so that $G(n,p)$ is the identity function. Generally, we try not to be too specific about what $\Omega$ is, though, because we might want other sources of randomness involved. We are happy as long as the distribution of $G(n,p)$ is correct: as long as $$\Pr[G(n,p) = G] = p^{|E(G)|} (1-p)^{\binom n2 - |E(G)|}.$$

We might also want to think of the graph evolution process, in which case $\Omega = [0,1]^{\binom n2}$. For each outcome $\omega \in \Omega$, $G(n,p)(\omega)$ includes the $i^{\text{th}}$ edge (order the edges however you like) if $\omega_i < p$. Here, we can define multiple graph valued random variables $G(n,p)$ and $G(n,p')$ in the same probability space.

Comment: what is the sample space here?

Comment: edited to mention the sample space as well

Comment: If $\Omega$ would be the same set of graphs and G(n,p) would be the identity function ie. $G(n,p)(\omega)=\omega$ where does $p$ come into play?

Comment: A probability space is a triple $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. In the "take $\Omega$ to be the same set of graphs" case, we assign $P(\omega) = p^{|E(\omega)|} (1-p)^{\binom n2 - |E(\omega)|}$.

Comment: why do we say that a random graph is a random variable and not an element of $\Omega$ and how can I show that the edges are satisitcally independent?

Comment: If we say that a random graph is an outcome of the probability space, then we've "hardcoded in" the probability space; we can't change it in any way. The point of random variables is to abstract away "implementation details": any process by which we obtain a graph at random can have the $G(n,p)$ distribution if it gets the same results with the same probabilities.

Comment: Statistical independence of edges depends on how you've defined the probability space. In the graph evolution example, it's particularly easy, because $\omega_i$ and $\omega_j$ are independent for $i \ne j$.

Comment: Last question why are $\omega_i$ and $\omega_j$ are independent for $i\neq j$.  ?An event has to be a subset of the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ what would be the subset in this case for the event $A$ that an edge existst and for the event $B$ that an other edge exists. And how could we show that $Pr(A\cap B)= Pr(A)Pr(B)$ ?

Comment: In that case the distribution on $\Omega$ is uniform, and probability is just $\binom n2$-dimensional volume, so you check that $\{\omega \in [0,1]^{\binom n2} : \omega_i < p\}$ and $\{\omega \in [0,1]^{\binom n2} : \omega_j < p\}$ are sets of volume $p$ whose intersection has volume $p^2$.